# Why Linux games are less performanced than Win 7?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, window, games

I had Windows 7 x64 and now I have Ubuntu 14.04 on notebook HP 4535s.
I expected games to be faster in Linux than on Windows because of fewer machine requirements. But it isn't so...
E.g., games via PlayOnLinux, but more performance I expected about games from Steam, but nothing.
Why? Do you have any tips for better performance?

(I didn't choose Linux because of games, but I want to play on it, too.)

HW = Notebook HP 4535s
Games = PlayOnLinux(World of Tanks, World of Warships, ...), Steam(CS:S, Stronghold 3, Hacker Evolution, ...)

```
prokop@prokop-pc:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sumo [Radeon HD 6480G]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
```

Comment: intel graphics? Nvidia? AMD?

Answer (score 2):

Its reasonable to expect PlayOnLinux to be a little heavier than native. PlayOnLinux relies on wine, which brings in a whole layer of virtualization overhead.

Steam on the otherhand is more of a grab-bag of some native games and some wine-wrappered games, so some will run smoother than others, depending on who/how it was ported.

Additionally, the difference between the opensource graphics drivers and the propitiatory drivers can make or break the gaming experience.

*These are just some broad generalizations, some specifics on your game/hardware would help.*

What is your graphics hardware/driver setup?
If you're unsure, this might help

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Comment: WINE = wine is not an emulator. There is actually no virtualization involved: check http://wiki.winehq.org/Debunking_Wine_Myths#head-7c9ecddfaff60d8891414b68d74277244e7109eb

Comment: -Unfortunately I have no experience with the ATI hardware. The only other thing I'd suggest would be to  ensure that you are running the proprietary Catalyst drivers rather than the open-source drivers. In gaming the difference can be very noticeable. This is also a point mentioned in the article linked by @tomodachi , and should be an easy fix in Ubuntu.

Comment: you should do a cpu and gpu benchmark that will first quantify the performance difference between windows and linux on your given hardware.  Google currently says Windows has 88% market share. Mac with 9% and linux 2% so i would NOT expect a game manufacturer to spend any effort on doing any kind of optimization for linux because it makes zero business sense